# Python Grab all links from a html and only display the links

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to grab the title out with of a webpage using the following statement:

```
titl1 = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>',the_webpage)
```

Using that, I get `['random webpage example1']`.  How do I remove the quotes and brackets?

---

I'm also trying to grab a set of links that change hourly (which is why I need the wildcard) using this: `links = re.findall(r'(file=(.*?).mp3)',the_webpage)`.

I get

```
[('file=http://media.kickstatic.com/kickapps/images/3380/audios/944521.mp3', 
  'http://media.kickstatic.com/kickapps/images/3380/audios/944521'), 
 ('file=http://media.kickstatic.com/kickapps/images/3380/audios/944521.mp3', 
  'http://media.kickstatic.com/kickapps/images/3380/audios/944521'), 
 ('file=http://media.kickstatic.com/kickapps/images/3380/audios/944521.mp3', 
  'http://media.kickstatic.com/kickapps/images/3380/audios/944521')]
```

How do I get the mp3 links without the `file=`?

---

I also want to download the mp3 files and append them with the title of the website so it will show

`random webpage example1.mp3`

How would I do this?  I'm still learning Python and regex and this is kinda stumping me.

Comment: [regex is generally not a good candidate for parsing XML/HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You might find [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) useful -- grabbing all links would be as simple as `soup.find_all('a')`. Take a look at [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: You should look at BeautifulSoup which is more suitable for url parsing.

Comment: Oh.. and you might find this useful for formatting your question: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

At least for part 1, you could do

```
>>> mytitle = title1[0]
>>> print mytitle
random webpage example1
```

The regex is returning a list of strings that match, so you just need to grab the first item on the list.

Similarly, for part two, the regex is returning a list with tuples inside.
You could do:

```
>>> download_links = [href for (discard, href) in links]
>>> print download_links
['http://media.kickstatic.com/kickapps/images/3380/audios/944521', 'http://media.kickstatic.com/kickapps/images/3380/audios/944521', 'http://media.kickstatic.com/kickapps/images/3380/audios/944521']
```

As for download files, use `urlib2` (at least for python 2.x, not sure about python 3.x).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python) for details.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st part
`titl1 = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>',the_webpage)` will return a list and when you print a list it is printed with the brackets and quotes. So try `print title[0]` if you are sure there will always be only one match. (You can also try re.search instead)

---

For the second part if you change your re pattern from `"(file=(.*?)\.mp3)"` to `"file=(.*?)\.mp3"` you will get only the `'http://linkInThisPart/path/etc/etc'` part you'll need to add the .mp3 extension though.

i.e

```
audio_links = [x +'.mp3' for x in re.findall(r'file=(.*?)\.mp3',web_page)]
```

---

To download the files you might want to look into urllib,urllib2

```
import urllib2
url='http://media.kickstatic.com/kickapps/images/3380/audios/944521.mp3'
req=urllib2.Request(url)
temp_file=open('random webpage example1.mp3','wb')
buffer=urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
temp_file.write(buff)
temp_file.close()
```

Comment: so when i use the                                                  links audio_links = [x +'.mp3' for x in re.findall(r'file=(.*?)\.mp3',web_page)]   all i get for a return are ['', '', '']

Comment: Try just a `.` instead of the `\.` ?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re,urllib,urllib2

Url = "http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/rick-ross-sixteen-feat-andre-3000"
print Url
print 'test .............'
req = urllib2.Request(Url)
print "1"
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print "2"
the_webpage = response.read()
print "3"
titl1 = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>',the_webpage)
print "4"
a2 = [x +'.mp3' for x in re.findall(r'file=(.*?)\.mp3',the_webpage)]
print "5"
a2 = [x[0][5:] for x in a2]
print "6"
ti = titl1[0]
print ti
print "7"
print a2
print "8"

print "9"
#print the_page
print "10"

req=urllib2.Request(a2)
print "11"
temp_file=open(ti)
print "12"
buffer=urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print "13"
temp_file.write(buff)
print "14"
temp_file.close()
print "15"
print "16"
```

Results

```
http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/rick-ross-sixteen-feat-andre-3000
test .............
1
2
3
4
5
6
Rick Ross - Sixteen (feat. Andre 3000)
7
['', '', '']
8
9
10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grub.py", line 29, in <module>
    req=urllib2.Request(a2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 198, in __init__
    self.__original = unwrap(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1056, in unwrap
    url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3:

```
import requests
import re
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
```

- **First get the HTML text**

```
html_text=requests.get('url')
```

- **regex find the urls**

> Regex pattern, match('pattern','text',flags)
>
> In the pattern, the '()' is used to group what you want. In this case, we group 'http://*****.mp3', and you can quote it by using .group(1) or groups().

```
url_find=re.findall('file=(http://media.mp3*',html_text)
for url_match in url_matches:
    index += 1
    print(url_match)
    urlretrieve(url_match, './graber/mp3/user' + str(index) + '.mp3')
```

That's how I complete, hope this will be helpful.(download things there are multiple ways, in this case,I use urlretrieve)